# accessing individual array elements in VBA function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, excel-2010

VBA newbie here. I am trying to pass an array (**it is static, but please answer for dynamic range as well**) to a function. Then assign individual array elements to unique variables and use these variables in a custom formula. I just browsed around and wrote the code but keep getting #VALUE! error. The gist of the code is below:

```
Public Function mytest(ByRef arr1 As Range)
Dim A As Double
Dim B As Double

A = arr1(0)
B = arr1(1)

mytest = A + B 'The actual formula is a bit more complicated than simple addition
End Function
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong at all. If anyone has a solution, can you please explain why it works as well. I appreciate any and all help I can get.
Many thanks !

Comment: A range is not an array. Do you want your function to accept worksheet ranges or VBA arrays, or both?

Comment: Hi John, for now I am looking to pass worksheet ranges to the function. Sorry for the confusion. BTW I also tried ByRef arr1() As Double. still got the #VALUE! error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Coleman pointed out a range is not an array, consider:

```
Public Function mytest(ByRef arr1 As Range)
    Dim A As Double
    Dim B As Double

    A = arr1(1, 1)
    B = arr1(2, 1)

    mytest = A + B 'The actual formula is a bit more complicated than simple addition
End Function
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- we treat the `Range` similar to an array
- it is two dimensional
- it is *1* based
- if you are only dealing with the `Range's` value, you could create an internal array within your function that directly maps to the passed `Range`.
- if the `Range` is truly dynamic, *(like a Spill range)* then all you need to pass is the anchor cell.

Comment: It is good to be explicit about the 1-based nature of range indexing, which trips up a lot of programmers coming to VBA from a C-like language

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to use a worksheet range as a 0-based array. That doesn't really make sense although using the `Cells` property of a range (which you are actually trying to do implicitly) you can come close:

```
Public Function mytest(arr1 As Range)
    Dim A As Double
    Dim B As Double

    A = arr1.Cells(1)
    B = arr1.Cells(2)

    mytest = A + B 'The actual formula is a bit more complicated than simple addition
End Function
```

In the above code, you can drop `Cells()` since it will function as the default property here, but most experienced VBA programmers like to make explicit what property they are using.

This will more or less work for 1-dimensional ranges but might not work as expected with 2-dimensional ranges. `Cells` takes up to 2 indices and in general I think that the code is clearer when you are explicit about the full indices (e.g. `A = arr1.Cells(1,1)` and `B = arr1.Cells(2,1)`).

Comment: Thanks John, this worked as well. This will be huge help ! I think it will still take me some practice to really get the differences between arrays and ranges. Just to followup, when I use ByRef arr1() as Double, can I still use the above code in the same way? What is the essential difference?

Comment: @anirudhkaushik you cannot, `Double` = number, numbers don't have coordinates. when you give a range you give an array of cells, when you give a number, it's just that.

Comment: @JohnColeman I was answering to anirudh's comment asking what happens if he uses `Double` instead of `Range` as parameter.

Comment: No problem John ;)

Comment: @Damian Doesn't using the brackets after arr1 make it an array? Or does VBA reads it as number regardless?

Comment: Sorry @anirudhkaushik, you are correct. Though that could give you errors if there is text on the cell, or your values have decimals, which the `Double` will ignore. If you mean to give back a `Double` as result for your function, the syntax is: `Public Function mytest(arr1 As Range) As Double`

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't in the code you posted but in the procedure that calls it. Here the calling procedure first assigns values to the cells in the worksheet (for testing purposes), then passes the range to the function which extracts the values into an array and then uses that array to calculate a return value.

```
Private Sub TestmyTest()

    Dim Rng1 As Range

    Cells(1, "A").Value = 3.14
    Cells(2, "A").Value = 3
    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:A2")

    Debug.Print myTest(Rng1)
End Sub

Function myTest(Rng1 As Range) As Double
    ' procedures are 'Public' unless declared as 'Private'
    ' Therefore only declare "Private" or nothing
    ' Arguments are passed ByRef unless they are declared as 'ByVal'
    ' Therefore I recommend to omit "ByRef"

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim A As Double
    Dim B As Double

    ' this creates a 1-based 3-D array of 2 row and 1 column
    Arr = Rng1.Value

    A = Arr(1, 1)
    B = Arr(2, 1)

    myTest = A + B 'The actual formula is a bit more complicated than simple addition
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Variatus ! Honestly speaking, many of the concepts/logic are still difficult for me to grasp. I have no real coding background and most of what I know is self learnt through online tutorials. But I will practice more and hopefully all of yours' answers will make more sense to me down the line.

Comment: Friendly hint to comment in function `myTest()`: *"this creates a 1-based 3-D array of 2 row and 1 column"* - this creates a 1-based *2-D* array :-;