# Element wise array operations in VBA Function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, for-loop

I have created a custom Function in VBA, the inputs to which are a cell value and three different ranges of the same length. The code is as below more or less:

```
Public Function MYTEST(CELLVALUE As Double, ByRef INPRNG As Range, ByRef RNG1 As Range, ByRef RNG2 As Range)
Dim i As Double
DIM A As Double
DIM B As Double
Dim MODRNG As Range

For i = LBound(INPRNG) To UBound(INPRNG)
    MODRNG(i) = INPRNG(i) * RNG1(i) + CELLVALUE * RNG2(i) 
Next i
A= MODRNG.Cells(1,1)
B= MODRNG.Cells(2,1)
mytest =A+B
End Function
```

I get a #VALUE! error when I run this code.
My question is three fold:

1. Are my variables/ranges declared incorrectly or is the For loop causing issues?
2. Is there a way to use For Each loop instead of For Next?
3. Can I do the array operation (of the for loop) in my excel worksheet and send the modified array to the function?

Please see the snap shot for clarity.[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of your input data? Though `MODRNG` shouldn't be a range if you are using math operators (which I assume will return a number).

Comment: So the data looks some thing like: "A1:A4"={1,2,3,4}    "B1:B4"={0,1,1,1}   "C9"=2  "D1:D4"  = {1,0,0,0}  . After the For Loop runs the final result should be an array MODRNG = {2,2,3,4}. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to input this formula in one cell and change 4 cells?

Comment: No, the final output of the function will be 'A+B', where values of A and B will be assigned from specific values of the array MODRNG. The values of MODRNG are calculated from the inputs sent to the function.

Comment: It would help if you added to your question a screenshot showing specific inputs and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your goal, but this will throw a number taking from first and second (cell/array position) for the MODRNG.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function MYTEST(CELLVALUE As Double, ByRef INPRNG As Range, ByRef RNG1 As Range, ByRef RNG2 As Range) As Long

    Dim i As Double
    Dim A As Double
    Dim B As Double
    ReDim MODRNG(1 To INPRNG.Cells.Count)

    For i = 1 To INPRNG.Cells.Count
        MODRNG(i) = INPRNG(i) * RNG1(i) + CELLVALUE * RNG2(i)
    Next i
    A = MODRNG(1)
    B = MODRNG(2)
    MYTEST = A + B

End Function
```

thought If you only want the first and second values, I don't see why would you take a range bigger than 2 cells.

Comment: Thanks, Damian, I will try this out to see if it works. I am only using two variables to give the readers a general idea.I am actual using alt the values (19 in all) of the actual range. These individual values are used to perform a complex mathematical operation. The function returns the value of this result back.

Comment: Well then remember that the `Range` Object needs the  `Set` statement, and is used to set Ranges as it says, so a valid result would be `Range("A1:A2")` if you intend to store numbers, use an array instead like the example I wrote here. Then you can dimension de array as large as your range with the `Cells.Count` for the range (if it's not a 2D range which means, more than 1 column for many rows or viceversa)

Comment: I am still getting #VALUE! error. Do I need to declare the MODRNG first? Or does ReDim defines it simultaneously? I tried using Dim MODRNG() as Double before ReDim. Didnt really help.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full code along with screenshoots of your input data and desired output?

Comment: The actual code is too long because of the number of math formula in it. I have added a snapshot  of the data points. FYI, the code works fine if I create the MODRNG outside and send a single array input to the function. This query is related to a separate question i asked earlier [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610817/accessing-individual-array-elements-in-vba-function?noredirect=1#comment108982638_61610817)